# Use of the mixed product for the Wikipedia description of Barycentric Co-ordinates

Tags: geometry

In reading Wikipedia entry for [Barycentric co-ordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#cite_note-Danby-3), the authors states without proof that for a vector $h \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and a basis $\{e,f,g \}$ that

$h = \frac{1}{(e,f,g)} \cdot [(h,f,g)e + (e,h,g)f+(e,f,h)g]$ where $(e,f,g) = (e \times f) \cdot g$

If $h = a_1 e_1 + a_2 e_2 + a_3 e_3$, then this amounts to saying that
$h = \frac{1}{(e_1 \times e_2) \cdot e_3} \cdot [((h \times e_2)\cdot e_3)e_1 + ((e_1 \times h) \cdot e_3)e_2+((e_1 \times e_2) \cdot h) e_3]$

The above formula I have manually verified, but I'm wondering why this is true for any basis?

Comment: Isn’t this simply Cramer’s rule for solving a system of linear equations?

Comment: @amd, so then $A$ would be the matrix whose columns are $e,f,g$, and $h$ would be $b$ in the typical $Ax = b$ formulation ? That seems right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an application of Cramer’s rule for solving systems of linear equations.

Recall that the coordinates of a vector are the coefficients of the unique linear combination of basis vectors that produces the vector. In other words, the coordinates of $h$ are the solution to the equation $h_1e+h_2f+h_3g = h$, which we can write as $$\begin{bmatrix}e&f&g\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}h_1\\h_2\\h_3\end{bmatrix} = h.$$ Now, the scalar triple product $(a,b,c)=a\times b\cdot c$ is equal to the determinant of $[a\;b\;c]$, so by Cramer’s rule, $$h_1 = {(h,f,g)\over(e,f,g)}, h_2 = {(e,h,g)\over(e,f,g)}, h_3 = {(e,f,h)\over(e,f,g)}.$$